# How to use a generic base controller with ActionFilters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using `ILogger<T>` and want it to be included in my base controller since every controller should use it.

I'm defining each derived class as `UsersController : BaseController<UsersController>`

In my base class I'm assigning `ILogger<T>` which works fine until I try to access the controller in my ActionFilter which I need to know how to cast it.

How do I achieve this or do it in a better way that accomplishes the same thing.

```
// Base Controller
public class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;
    protected readonly ILogger<T> _logger;
}

// Instance Controller
public class UsersController : BaseController<UsersController>
{
    public UsersController(ILogger<UsersController> logger,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) 
        : base(logger, appSettings)
    {
        ...
    }

// ActionFilter used to set viewbag on all pages/layout pages
public class ViewBagActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Can't use typeof() or nameof()
        if (context.Controller.GetType().BaseType.Name == "BaseController")
        {
            // This doesn't work either
            var controller = context.Controller as BaseController;
            controller.ViewBag.Username = controller?.User?.Username;
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also have a Interface, that is only for setting the ViewBag... like IViewbagHolder...but what prevents you from setting the ViewBag Username for every Controller. It’s part of the ControllerBase isn’t it?

Comment: I can't find the SO link but it says that if you want to use Viewbag on a _layout page, you should do it this way for aspnet core. Viewbag is populated after layout is rendered I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear, what I meant.
Instead of using BaseController-Class in your Action-Filter, just use ControllerBase... it already has the ViewBag-Property, hasn’t it?
This is my suggestion:

```
// Base Controller
public class BaseController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;
    protected readonly ILogger<T> _logger;
}

// Instance Controller
public class UsersController : BaseController<UsersController>
{
    public UsersController(ILogger<UsersController> logger,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) 
        : base(logger, appSettings)
    {
        ...
    }

// ActionFilter used to set viewbag on all pages/layout pages
public class ViewBagActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        
        // This could work I think, but untested 
        var controller = context.Controller as ControllerBase;
        controller.ViewBag.Username = controller?.User?.Username;
        

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you have Properties, that need to be accessible in Filters, you can define an Interface like this:

```
public interface IAccessible
{
   // your Properties here
   string UserName { get;}
   dynamic ViewBag { get;}
   //...
}
```

And implement it in your BaseController... you see, the interface doesn’t have to be generic...
Then you can use it in you filter like:

```
var controller = context.Controller as IAccessible;
        controller.ViewBag.Username = controller?.Username;
```

Comment: I need access to properties on my base class. i.e. `controller?.User`

Comment: For this purpose, you could use an Interface.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this out yet but I like this idea!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help but `ILogger<T>` inherits from `ILogger` so you could just have your base controller not be generic:

```
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;
}
```

and the constructor in your inherited controller will still work.

Comment: I'll test this out and see if it works. From what I've read you "have to" use the generic version for DI.